# Changing Oembed max width based type of page

Tags: oembed

How do i change/filter the oembed max width settings (as set by ) admin -> media -> settings -> "Maximum embed size" before the oembed code gets executed.  For example on the index pages i want it to be 540, but ona single page, i'd like to be 880?

Answer (score 1):

Using the following in your **functions.php** file should do the trick:

```
/**
 *  Configure default oEmbed video sizes
 */
function base_oembed_defaults($embed_size) {
    if( is_single() ) {
        $embed_size['width'] = 580;
        $embed_size['height'] = 435;
    }
    return $embed_size;
}
add_filter('embed_defaults', 'base_oembed_defaults');
```

Add as many [WordPress conditional statements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) as you like to match the desired aspect ratio for each template.